# Initializing an AnyObject property in a Swift class?

Tags: ios, swift, class, object, uiimageview

Ok so I am trying to create a class that creates bullet points in the Swift programming language. However I am having trouble figuring out how to initialize the style of the bullet point.

After initializing a bullet point object I want to be able to select whether the style of the bullet point will be an imported image in which case that property will conform to a `UIImageView` or (on default) the style of the bullet point will become an auto-incrementing number value and conform to a `UILabel`.

For example, I want the structure of the class to look something like this:

```
class bullet {

    var bulletStyle: AnyObject

    init() {
        bulletStyle = UILabel()
    }

    init(styleImage style:UIImageView) {
        bulletStyle = style
    }
}
```

However after testing the class, `bulletStyle` is still taking on the type `AnyObject` after initializing the class both ways. So how can I set `bulletStyle` to either a `UILabel` object or a `UIImageView` object on initialization?

Comment: After initialization, `bulletStyle` does have an underlying value of `UILabel` or `UIImageView`, but its type is `AnyObject`, which, in accordance with Swift's type safety features, cannot be changed after the variable has been declared.

Comment: You could try something like wrapping your object into a custom class instead of using AnyObject. Then you can add logic to handle whatever your use case is.

Comment: @aaplmath Right... but if I initialize a new instance of bullet, say: `var newBullet = bullet()` and then I try to change the text of the bulletStyle because it initialized to the default `UILabel` such as: `newBullet.bulletStyle.text` it doesn't recognize that `bulletStyle` has a property of `.text` and throws an error.

Comment: @WillM. How do I do this?

Comment: You can also use type casting. So rather than typing `newBullet.bulletStyle.text`, you would write something along the lines of `(newBullet.bulletStyle as! UILabel).text`, though this goes against the type safety of Swift and probably is not an optimal setup.

Comment: especially not optimal if you are doing it all over the place because you have an object that can be two different types

Comment: So is there no way to initially set what type of object it will be when a bullet object is first initialized? That is what I am really trying to get at... At this point I'm thinking I should just have two different properties and use case logic to determine which one to use

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a protocol. You create a protocol BulletStyle, and you create 2 classes that implement this protocol. Below is a code example.

```
protocol BulletStyle {

    var bulletText: String? { get set}

    var bulletImage: UIImage? { get set}

}

class Bullet {

    var bulletStyle: BulletStyle

    init() {
        bulletStyle = BulletLabel()
    }

    init(styleImage style:BulletImageView) {
        bulletStyle = style
    }
}

class BulletLabel: UILabel, BulletStyle {

    var bulletText: String? {
        get {
            return self.text
        }
        set {
            self.text = newValue
        }
    }

    var bulletImage: UIImage? {
        get {
            return nil
        }
        set {
           // nothing to set
        }
    }

}

class BulletImageView: UIImageView, BulletStyle {

    var bulletText: String? {
        get {
            return nil // no text for an image
        }
        set {
            // nothing to set for an image
        }
    }

    var bulletImage: UIImage? {
        get {
            return self.image
        }
        set {
            self.image = newValue
        }
    }

}


class YourApp {

    var myBullets : [BulletStyle]?

    func createBullets() {
        myBullets = [BulletLabel(), BulletLabel(), BulletImageView()]
        myBullets![0].bulletText = "bulletA"
        myBullets![1].bulletText = "bulletB"
        myBullets![2].bulletImage = UIImage(named: "myBulletImageA")
    }

}
```

Comment: This idea to use two subclasses conforming to the same protocol is sound, but not in this way. The whole protocol should be relevant to both classes, not half of it for one class and the other half for the other class. Think about what the bullet needs as external interface on a logical level, and make sure that both bullet classes implement that in a relevant way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't agree that there is anything wrong with the protocol. It’s all about the semantics of the protocol. The protocol is the contract that says: "A BulletStyle implementation is required to specify wether it has a text or not. If it hasn’t, the implementation must return return nil". Same for image. This contract is relevant for both classes. I could extend the example with another BulletStyle implementation that has both image and text. However, I do agree that the example could have been simpler by taking a common attribute like size or indentationLevel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's comments and replies. I was originally hoping that there was a way to change a variables type, but now realize that this is definitely discouraged and goes against Swift's own type safety features.

The reason for wanting to change the variables type was because I wanted to create auto-layout constraints on all of the bullet object's properties. I knew going into this that since  `UIImageView`'s and `UILabel`'s both inherit from `UIView`, it would be much easier to initially determine and set a single variable depending on the case, that way I would only have to worry about creating a single set of `NSLayoutConstraint`'s, using that one variable.

Anyway I answered my own question and decided the best solution is to create an additional `UIView` object to act as a container for each case. I'm still only using a single variable and a single set of `NSLayoutConstraint`'s to set whether the container should hold a `UIImageView` or `UILabel`. Also, by doing it this way, going forward I could just use the single container object for the additional constraints that would be needed.

Here is what it looks like:

```
class bullet {

    var bulletStyleContainer: UIView

    init(bulletStyle: AnyObject) {

        bulletStyleContainer = UIView()
        createBulletStyle(bulletStyle)
    }

    func createBulletStyle(style: AnyObject) {

        if style is UIImageView {

            bulletStyleContainer.addSubview(style as! UIImageView)

        } else if style is UILabel {

            bulletStyleContainer.addSubview(style as! UILabel)

        } else {

            let style = style as! UIView
            style.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            bulletStyleContainer.addSubview(style)

        }

        let leftPinConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: style, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: bulletStyleContainer, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let rightPinConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bulletStyleContainer, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: style, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let topPinConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: style, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: bulletStyleContainer, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let bottomPinConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bulletStyleContainer, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: style, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        style.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leftPinConstraint,rightPinConstraint,topPinConstraint,bottomPinConstraint])

    }
```

Comment: I still feel that @Peter's proposal to create two bullet classes with a common protocol would be a better solution. One of the bullet classes derives from UILabel, and the other from UIImage, in order to satisfy your demands for the constraints.

Comment: If you choose this approach at least I'd suggest that you change the type of bulletStyle into UIView.